# AngularJS: Is it possible to access html element that called a function in the ng-hide directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am new to angularjs. Is it possible to access the html element that called a function in the ng-hide directive? I know that ng-click provides the $event which can be used to access the element. However, $event is not available for ng-hide. Furthermore, passing the 'this' keyword as a parameter only passes $scope and even jquery's $(this) keyword is useless.

```
<h1 class="slide ng-scope" index="0" ng-hide="!isCurrentIndex()">Welcome</h1>
```

The isCurrentIndex() function is designed to access the index attribute of the element and compare that to a variable that stores the current index. It returns a boolean.

Please any help is appreciated.

```
           $templateRequest(scope.slides[i].url).then(function(t){
                var template = angular.element(t);
                template.attr("class", "slide");
                template.attr("index",scope.indicator.toString());
                template.attr("ng-hide","!isCurrentIndex()");
                $("#slide-content").append(template);
                $compile(template)(scope);
                ++scope.indicator;
            });
```

Comment: How is the index attribute set?

Comment: Is this html generated dynamically or it is a hard coded html template? I suppose that more than one h1 tag is available and you want to show the right one. Am I right?

Comment: Hi Malk. It is set in an initialization function on page load. Its index corresponds to a particular index in an array.

Comment: The html is created dynamically and then compiled - $compile(html)(scope);. Yes, thadam that is correct. There is more than one h1 and I want to display the correct one.

Comment: Is the `<h1>` created in an `ng-repeat`?

Comment: If there is an ng-repeat and your index is equal to ng-repeat index then just put it as a parameter into the function as suggested in answer by Brent Washburne

Comment: Hi Josh, no. See the edit for example.

Comment: It seems you can pass the index the same way you set it..`"!isCurrentIndex('" + scope.indicator.toString() + "')"`. It doesn't really answer your question of how to access the element. I think you want to call in a directive for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From personal experience forget about accessing data attributes like you did in jQuery.
Try to use the angular way of doing things.
A good reference for a good start is this git repo:
[Angular Styleguide by johnpapa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)

Back to your question.
Is this what you try to achieve?

controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.isCurrentIndex = isCurrentIndex;
    $scope.index = 0;
    function isCurrentIndex(index){
       return $scope.index === index;
    }
}
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h1 class="slide" ng-hide="!isCurrentIndex(0)">Welcome</h1>
    <h1 class="slide" ng-hide="!isCurrentIndex(1)">to</h1>
    <h1 class="slide" ng-hide="!isCurrentIndex(2)">ng-hide</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Kozer! Awsome. I just needed to put the index right into the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the id as the parameter:

```
... id="id_welcome" ng-hide="!isCurrentIndex('id_welcome')"> ...
```